# How to set different background colors of yAxis headers in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I want to set some different background colors for some of the yAxis headers, you can see what I want in this case in the below picture:

for example, I want to set red color for Planning header and their children, and set yellow for Develop header and their children.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Meysam Zarei, Do you want to set background color for all of the marked area or only for labels: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lc4g1muq/ ?

Comment: @ppotaczek Hi, I just want to set background color for all of the marked area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to add rect elements behind the labels. Example:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
      x = yAxis.right,
      y1 = yAxis.top,
      y2 = yAxis.top + yAxis.translationSlope * 5,
      w = yAxis.left - this.spacingBox.x,
      h1 = yAxis.translationSlope * 5,
      h2 = yAxis.translationSlope * 3;

    if (!yAxis.customBG) { // render
      yAxis.customBG = this.renderer.rect(
        x,
        y1,
        w,
        h1
      ).attr({
        fill: 'red'
      }).add();

      yAxis.customBG2 = this.renderer.rect(
        x,
        y2,
        w,
        h2
      ).attr({
        fill: 'yellow'
      }).add();

    } else { // reposition
      yAxis.customBG.attr({
        x: x,
        y: y1,
        width: w,
        height: h1
      });

      yAxis.customBG2.attr({
        x: x,
        y: y2,
        width: w,
        height: h2
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/naL810ye/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Thanks, and how can I set this background-color to their next column?

Comment: Hi @Meysam Zarei, In the same way. Just use again `renderer.rect` method.